# Can't change tasks to realtime priotity

Tags: windows-7, windows, task-manager, priority

I just want to change a running task's priority to realtime, but the taskmanager won't let me do it. If I try it, it'll just tell me that it can't change to realtime and then changes it to high instead.

I created a link to the task manager. Ran the link as administrator. And still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you need something real-time? It's not exactly something common.

Comment: There's an application I want to leave running, but it slows down terribly whenever it's unfocused. Not sure if setting it to real time is gonna make a difference, but I thought I'd give it a try. (and I will, shortly)

Comment: Set it to high priority is good enough.

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it and setting it to realtime didn't do any good that high could do, the issue must be within the application. Worth a try anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from Sysinternals. Make sure to run it as Administrator. Also what process are you trying to change? Certain services don't allow this for stability reasons.

[image]

Comment: Seems to have worked. I think the shorcut I created just wasn't really running as admin.  
Thanks